# Crystal Reports group header showing balance while its details showing another figures

Tags: crystal-reports

I am doing a stock report and seeing the movement of the sales for each item as well as its remaining stock would be more useful. However, I can generate the report as below except for the values in **bold**, which is the remaining stock of each item. What can I do to have the remaining balance at the group header? Thank you so much.
(note that items1,2,.. are a group header and customers1,2,3,... are details)

> item1  >>>   **10 *(remaining stock)***
>
> ```
>                  (jan feb mar apr total)
>
>   customer1        2   4   5   -   11 (sales)
>   customer2        -   2   1   1   4  (sales)
>   customer3        -   -   -   2   2  (sales)
>     total          2   6   6   3   17
> ```
>
> item2  >>>    **56 (remaining stock)**
>
> ```
>   customer4        1   3   3   4   11 (sales)
>   customer2        -   3   5   2   10  (sales)
>   customer5        7   9   6   4   26  (sales)
>     total          8  15  14  10   47
> ```